# SQL script to kill all blocked processes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, kill, kill-process

I'm trying to create an SQL script that will kill all blocked process.

Am I missing something?

```
declare @max_count int, @count int, @sqlstring varchar(100)
declare @spid_table table (spid int NOT NULL)

INSERT @spid_table
select spid
from master.dbo.sysprocesses
where spid in (select blocked from master.dbo.sysprocesses where blocked > 0) 

select @max_count = MAX(spid) FROM @spid_table
select top 1 @count = spid from @spid_table

while @count <= @max_count
begin
select @sqlstring = 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(4), @count)
exec(@sqlstring)
end
```

Comment: A little mistake - `WHERE spid IN (SELECT spid /*blocked*/ ....)`

Comment: Kill the blocked ones? Well sure, shoot the innocent, instead of investigating at the bully (the blocker)...

Comment: @RemusRusanu so how do you fine the bully? is there a much better way of finding the culprit? rather than where blocked >0?

Comment: Yes, the `blocked` is SPID of the blocker. Apply recursively until you find the top of the chain, the one that is blocking w/o being blocked. Investigate what is *that* doing. Use a tool like [`sp_whoisactive`](http://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a way to increment through your `@spid_table`. You should add two lines inside your `while` after the `exec`

```
DELETE FROM @spid_table WHERE spid = @count
SELECT @count = spid FROM @spid_table
```

or add IDENTITY column to `@spid_table` and use it for loop.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + 'KILL ' + CAST(spid as VARCHAR(5))
    FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
    WHERE blocked != 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```